# UICollectionView in UIControl - delegate & datasource

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicontrol

I've added a `UICollectionView` to a `UIControl` (which is being called in a `UITableViewController` section header) and the `UICollectionView` is appearing (background color shows), but the datasource and delegate seem to be ignored - no cells are showing and a print statement in my `dequeueReusableCell` function isn't being called (but one in the `UIControl` `init` method is. Can you tell me what I'm missing here?

**My UIControl:**

```swift
// Stripped down code
final class My_Control: UIControl {
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addSubview(myCV)
  }

  private let myCV: Custom_CV = {
    let cv: Custom_CV = Custom_CV()
    return cv
  }()
}
```

**My Collection View:**

```swift
final class Custom_CV: UIControl, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addSubview(collectionView)        
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
  }

  func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .red
    print("Building cell") // Not being called
    return cell
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 72.0, height: 72.0)
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //
  }

  private let cellIdentifier: String = "cellIdentifier"

  private let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout: UICollectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewLayout()
    let collectionView: UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    return collectionView
  }()
}
```

I think I'm missing something obvious, but I don't see it. I'm expecting to see 10 red squares and 10 print statements, but I get nothing there. But as I said - it's definitely being called because the a print statement in `My_CV`'s init was being called, and I can see the `.white` background for the collectionview in `My_Control`.